# Sudoku with AC3

Tags: java, algorithm, sudoku, backtracking

I am trying to implement a sudoku problem in java. At the moment I have managed to make the naive implementation of the backtracking, and it seems to be working, but what I need is to use the AC3 algorithm. I have seen the pseudo-code for it on several sources : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC-3_algorithm (one example) and I am wondering what would be the restraints.

```
function arc-reduce (x, y)
 bool change = false
 for each vx in D(x)
     find a value vy in D(y) such that vx and vy satisfy the constraint R2(x, y)
     if there is no such vy {
         D(x) := D(x) - vx
         change := true
     }
 return change
```

To be more specific, I send X, Y as 2 nodes :

```
class Node{
 int i,j;
}
```

Each node holds the coordinates of an element in my sudoku table. But what do I use for the R2 constraint?

My current try :

```
  Map m; //contains a map with structure <i,j,List> where i and j are the coordinates in the sudoku table, and List is the initial Domain of that spot on the table;  

  public boolean arc-reduce(Node x, Node y){ 
  ArrayList l1 = m.get(x.i,x.j);
  ArrayList l2 = m.get(y.i,y.j);

  char one,two;
  boolean found=false, change=false;

  for(int a=0;a<l1.size();a++){
     one = l1.get(a);
     found = false;            

     for(int b=0;b<l2.size();b++){
     two = l2.get(b);

         if(one==two && x.i==y.i) //same char same line
             found=true;
         if(one==two && x.j==y.j) //same char same column
             found=true;

     }
     if(found==false){
     l1.remove(i);
     change=true;
     }

  }
  return change;
  }
```

At it's current state the modified domains I get after applying this are not correct. Is there a flaw in my implementation? I would appreciate some hints to set me in the right direction, because this problem is giving me quite the trouble.

Comment: Could you describe without using code the formulation of Sudoku that you want?

Comment: The typical 9x9 board with no duplicates on same line or column, maybe even in the same 3x3 box.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with Sudoku, but there are many ways to choose variables and constraints.

Answer (score 3):

The R2 constraints are binary constraints, between two variables. In Sudoku, there are 3 different binary constraint types. For a given node (square) n of the Sudoku: (1) Every node in n's row must not have the same value as n. (2) Every node in n's column must not have the same value as n. (3) Every node in the same square as n must not have the same value as n. 
You need to formulate these constraints as your R2 constraints.  You don't need to do it exactly as the psuedocode does, that is just an outline for the algorithm.  The idea for the Sudoku is that when you make an assignment or change the domain of a node, you must enforce consistency with the domains of the nodes it has a relation with (reduce the domains of those in the same row, column and square).  Hope that helps you.